# An Error Was Encountered Unable to load the requested file: helpers/form_validation_helper.php

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, php-5.5

Log in page is not working in my project during, so it says

> Unable to load the requested file: helpers/form_validation_helper.php

I have already loaded the mentioned file in config file of my project. But still it is not working.

Controller is include two function `auth` function check the authentication and `index` function which load the view

login controller source code:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('pages/login');
    }

    function auth() {
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helpers('form_validation');

        $rules = array(
                    array(
                        'field' => 'username',
                        'label' => 'Username',
                        'rules' => 'required'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'field' => 'password',
                        'label' => 'Password',
                        'rules' => 'required'
                    )
                ); 
        $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

        if($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
            $this->load->view('pages/login');
        } else {
            echo "valid form";
        }
    }
}
```

login view source code:

```
<body>
    <section class="container">
        <div class="login">
            <h1>Login to Web App</h1>
            <?php $this->load->helper('form');
            echo validation_errors();
            echo form_open('login/auth');
            $username = form_input(array('name'=> 'username', 'placeholder' => 'username or Email'));
            $password = form_password(array('name' => 'password', 'placeholder' => 'password'));
            $checkbox = form_checkbox('remember', '1');
            $submit = form_submit('submit','Login')
            ?>

            <p><?=$username;?></p>
            <p><?=$password;?></p>
            <p class="remember_me">
                <label>
                    <?=$checkbox;?>
                    Remember me on this computer
                </label>
            </p>
            <p class="submit"><?=$submit;?></p>
            <?php form_close(); ?>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Form validation is not a helper, it is a library:

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
```

Please correct it.

Comment: In this case how to redirect from model to controller, please help me!!

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly you want? I am not getting you?

Answer (score 0):

Actually form_validation is a library, not a helper

so you can use

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
```

not

```
  $this->load->helpers('form_validation');
```